# Bind parsed XML data to AngularJS variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml

Im trying to bind XML data to a variable in AngularJS.

The data returned from my service is in XML

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
&lt;Response&gt;&#xD;
  &lt;Firstname&gt;Johanna&lt;/Firstname&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/Response&gt;</string>
```

I then use x2js to parse the xml and get this returned:

```
var jsonResponse = x2js.xml_str2json(response);
```

[image]

Finally I want to bind Firstname to $scope.firstname

This is where I need help. I dont know what to do to bind the value. 
What ive tried:

```
$scope.firstname = jsonResponse.Response.Firstname;
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Firstname' of undefined

$scope.firstname = jsonResponse.Object.Object.toString.__text.Response.Firstname
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
```

Ive tried a bunch of different combinations to try get to Firstname but none are working. I either get the above error or an undefined message.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your xml string to which contains special characters needs to decode in HTML and than convert it to JSON please find below snippet for more information.

I have added a function for `DecodeHTML` similarly you can choose if you have any other option to Decode it.

```js
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
var x2js = new X2JS();
var xmlstring = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Response&gt;&#xD;&lt;Firstname&gt;Johanna&lt;/Firstname&gt;&#xD;&lt;/Response&gt;</string>';

var formattedXML = decodeHtml(xmlstring);
var xmlTOjson = x2js.xml_str2json(formattedXML);

var FirstName = xmlTOjson.string.Response.Firstname;

alert(FirstName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdmob/x2js/master/xml2json.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you